Evil God Challenge: What if an evil god is just trolling humanity and that explains why there's good in the world?
I've been reading up on the idea of there being an evil god. There's a lot of interesting arguments but I haven't come across anyone mentioning this argument: that all the goodness in the world is just an evil god trolling humanity collectively into a false sense of security about the nature of the world (either that there's an afterlife if you believe in that or that we vanish into nothingness when we die). But when we die the evil god will reveal it's trolling, thus pulling the rug from under our feet, and then torment/afflict torture upon us forever.
I've heard arguments made that "If God is all-powerful, why would He create you, and this world with all its beauty, and your mind, and your soul, just to torture you?" But the answer could be that it's just fun to an evil god to do that.
I've also heard "If there is such a powerful being, they'd be really petty and immature to be mean to some particular humans among billions on this big rock, orbiting one of hundreds of billions of stars in our gigantic galaxy, which is one of hundreds of billions of galaxies in our colossal universe." But an evil god could be that petty and immature.
How I see it, I can't think of a hypothetical argument that refutes the idea of an evil god that is just trolling humanity. Any argument you make could just be answered as the evil god is just fucking with you but when you die, you'll finally know the truth about the world.
Truth be told, this is a frightening idea to me and I'd love if someone could refute this idea of a "trolling" evil god.

What goodness in this world requires or even permits for any supernatural influence?

Meditation with proper instruction can be helpful in overcoming negative states of mind.

I trust you truly do subscribe to the tenet that the pleasure one might derive from a proposition’s truth value cannot affect what that truth value actually is.

It's just profoundly egocentric to imagine that the universe operates in a humanlike social hierarchy with a boss man at the top. Science has shown that humans are just one particular ape produced by randomized mechanical processes on one particular planet. Social hierarchies are just one particular adaptation of this one particular ape. It's grotesque to project it as something fundamental to the universe.

It is profoundly anthropocentric. But the Buddha transformed himself into a little rabbit to be eaten by a hungry tiger :) Acts of kindness, even when apparently absurd, cannot be wiped out by future events.

Also, to act (or fail to act) in the hope of a future reward or out of fear for a future punishment shows a crude, childish, inherently authoritarian form of moral sense. It's unfortunate that many people raised in Abrahamic traditions seem to remain stuck in that.

The first paragraph describes almost perfectly the idea and modus operandi of Satan.  The good news, (if you believe...) is that there is also good to balance the evil, and a way out for believers.

God is not a "boss man." He is Spirit.

Not an expert of religions, however I don't think that your idea is totally original. In some way there are many "evil gods" in past (and current?) religions. Maybe your original idea is a god cheating in this life for torturing us after the death. Maybe original only because in the past, and also today outside of the wealthy areas of the world, this life is already hard for thinking of a worst afterlife. Anyway, there is nothing that guarantees us that there isn't an "evil god". But I think that 1) For believers, good news is that God is good; 2) For anyone, believer or not, we are NOT God.

@causative While I've +1ed ur comment, the correct word I believe is anthropomorphic more than egoistic — the collective ego of the human species so to speak...

@Rushi Anthropomorphism is a result of egocentrism. The properties of man are the properties of yourself, and so by projecting these properties onto the universe you inflate your self-image. Theists feel "special" that they are favored by God, especially if they can point to a lot of other people who aren't so favored. It damages their ego to think they are descended from an ape or from space dust.

This is an example of an hypothesis which cannot be refuted by logic. Scientists compare such a hypothesis to the null hypothesis (no such god exists). Is there any evidence that he/she/it does exist? Is there any experiment one can perform to determine whether or not it does? If neither, the hypothesis is useless and can be and should be  ignored since it is uselessly more complicated than the null hypothesis. This is known as Occam's Razor. In everyday language, take the world as you find it and don't invent imaginary things to fear.

@mudskipper "the Buddha transformed himself into a little rabbit to be eaten by a hungry tiger"  wait, did that really happen?

@Andy - I embellished the story a bit, but see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Sattva :)

Have you ever read the Bible? If you’re looking for evidense of a deity with a rather questionable sense of morality, you don’t need to concoct elaborate scenarios involving divine trolling. Just crack open that good book and prepare for a litany of divine misadventares that would make any evil god blush with envy.
Consider the following greatest hits from the Holy Scriptures -
The Great Flood. Our benevolent deity gets so peeved with humanity that he decides to drown every living creature, save for a select few. Talk about overkill! Why not just a divine timeout or a stern letter of reprimand? Then Abraham and Isaac. God plays a sadistic game of “Gotcha!” with Abraham, commanding him to sacrifice his son, only to pull the plug at the last second. It’s like a cosmic prank show, but with much higher stakes.
Job’s Trials. Poor Job. He’s the subject of a wager between God and Satan. God allows Satan to ruin Job’s life, just to test his faith. Because nothing says love like turning someone’s existence into a celestial bet. Also if you ever doubted God’s flair for the dramatic, look no further than the ten plagues. Rivers of blood, swarms of locusts, and death of the firstborns—an extravagant display of divine wrath that would make any evil deity proud.
Canaanite Genocide. God commands the Israelites to commit genocide, wiping out entire populations, including women and children. That’s not just trolling—that’s a full-on massacre endorsed by the Almighty. And of course Hell. Eternal torment for finite crimes? Oh, how quaint. An evil god couldn’t devise a more diabolical punishment system. Eternal fire and brimstone for the slightest infraction? A masterpiece of malevolent creativity.
So, you see, the idea that an evil god might be trolling us with intermittent goodness is almost redundant. The deity described in the Bible seems to have a penchant for actions that any self-respecting evil god would applaud. The real challenge isn’t imagining an evil god—it’s reconciling the one we already have in the scriptures with any notion of benevolence.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I don't understand why, if an evil god is trolling humanity, while the bible is relevant.  It would seemingly just be a fiction, designed to further the purpose.

The simple answer is Occam's razor. It is, of course, also the answer to religion in general as opposed to simply taking things as they are.
Your idea — like any religion — is essentially paranoid: You invent a story that's impossible to refute; it has built-in mechanisms to ad-hoc counter any argument brought against it: "Oh, that? that's just another devilishly mean way to fuck with us!", which is your equivalent to the Christians' "His ways are ineffable."
If things could be the way they are without the story, leave it out.

Although Occam himself was a theologian, so either he didn't apply the razor rule to the argument, or he applied it in a way different from yours.

@FabiusWiesner I didn't want to complicate a simple argument so I didn't add that tangent to my post but: In pre-historic times, imagining an animated nature is probably a very reasonable thing to do. With growing knowledge, Occam's razor led to monotheism (why would every well have its own fairy if He simply created all water and the laws that govern it!?). In Occam's time, a single creator was the best and simplest explanation with the fewest variables. (Paradoxically, it was the only thing he found necessary!). That has only changed with modern science. Occam was a genius -- in the 1300s.

@Peter I am not very knowleadgeable, but assuming Wikipedia is well written and not biased, in the "Faith and reason" paragraph of William of Ockham page, he seemed to separate science (even science of 1300) from religion, very modern to my eyes (although I am probably biased), anyway centuries before others.

Er... I assume, from this post, that you don't like religion, but merely stating "Occam's Razor" isn't really an answer to... anything. I think this is a pretty low-effort answer. Occam's Razor isn't some philosophical axiom that you can invoke whenever something conflicts with your prior assumptions.

@AmagicalFishy In my opinion, the level of thought exposed by the answer corresponds to the level of thought exposed by the question.-- Can you elaborate why and how you find the principle of Occam's razor arbitrary -- generally and specifically? I find it enormously helpful in general and cannot see here specifically how the idea to explain the workings of the world from (known) first principles is not superior to telling an extrinsic story on top.

The core of this answer is absolutely on point — but it’s let down by the sideswipe “…like all religions…”, which is a huge and unnecessary distraction, as the comments are showing.  There are plenty of pro-theistic arguments that are much more sophisticated than this question, and can’t be demolished quite so briefly.  (I’m not religious myself, but recognise that some pro-god arguments are easier to dismiss than others.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Occam's Razor is a philosophical heuristic—not an answer to the question. A religious person using Occam's Razor comes to different conclusions than does an Atheist using it. A quote taken from Wikipedia: "Occam's razor is not an embargo against the positing of any kind of entity, or a recommendation of the simplest theory come what may. Occam's razor is used to adjudicate between theories that have already passed 'theoretical scrutiny' tests and are equally well-supported by evidence."

@Peter-ReinstateMonica i.e. - Assumptions about the existence of an evil trolling god that rules the universe or whatever aren't dismissed by a mere invocation of Occam's Razor. If you believe the "simpler" explanation of existence is absent of a god or whatever other entity [which you seem to], and the OP doesn't [which they seem not to], then you're at an impasse.

@AmagicalFishy I believe I heard "evidence" somewhere?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, specifically in the sentence: "Occam's razor is used to adjudicate between theories that have already passed 'theoretical scrutiny' tests and are equally well-supported by evidence." By using Occam's Razor here, you  must be implying that the Evil-God and No-God worlds are  both equally well supported by evidence. That's what you meant, correct? Or was it just a lazy attempt to legitimize disparaging religion as "essentially paranoid"?

On the other hand, if you try to apply Occam's Razor to the Evil-God and Benevolent-God worlds, the obvious question is: Why would one be a "simpler" explanation than the other? Either way, regardless of my opinion of the question, Occam's Razor isn't an answer.

I think you are an evil German, Peter.

@GraySheep I can assure you that you are at least 50% correct, which is about the level of a monkey hitting the keyboard. ;-)

I think that you are coming at this from a good attempt but the wrong angle. Your title asks the more apt question than your post, and they need to be addressed separately. Let me first satisfy the mistaken angle and then I can address the important issue. The problem is trying to solve large fundamental questions the same tools you use to address smaller, oversimplified questions. I do like your thought experiment, though, and personally, I use something somewhat similar in my own philosophical approach.
The oversimplified question
Can we refute any type of god? Can we refute any non-self contradictory thing? Not without unnecessary assumptions and begging the question. Descartes says that the only thing we can know undeniably is the Cogito. Every other possible state of reality, even complete control by malevolent demons, or by extrapolation, deities, or even no deities at all, is within the realm of potentially true. So, the simple answer is "No", but that's saying less about the nature of a potential god as it is about our ability to handle things by deduction through pure reason alone.
Asking a better question
Most of the time, when we explore beliefs, we actually start from a fairly large set of presumptions. This is probably slightly different for everybody, but often includes things like assumptions about how our minds and reason work, what the meaning of life is, and all sorts of other things. We then compare new information to these fundamentals, so most of the time we're skipping a lot of steps. This is fine for the small questions, but not for the big ones. When we attempt to ask questions that challenge these core beliefs, we find that the tools we were using themselves were based upon presumptions which we now question. Therefore, this method is not useful for this larger task. We need to start from first principles like Descartes, but we need to add something more to pass beyond Solipsism, or really to narrow our goal in some way.
The better question is the "What if...?" I think that your question hints at the other necessary component, which I believe to be "impetus". Why should we or should we not believe a thing? We can believe a thing. We can believe many strange things, and reason cannot by itself refute them. The box of unrefutable things is simply too large. However, if we narrow that list down to unrefutable practical things, then now we have a useful classification. It could be possible that I do not have the ability to reason. It could be possible that the time is instantaneous. It could be possible that regardless what I believe, the outcome would be the same for me. However, it is not practical to believe any of those things, and several others, and once I can establish their inverse, I can start to build a system which can be useful.
What should we believe
So, starting with reason and impetus, what can we say about such a trickster god? I think that we can say that we should not believe in such a thing. The reason is that we have nothing to gain by believing in such a thing. If our minds or nature were controlled or influenced in a way such that we could not come to true conclusions by using our minds and reason, then we couldn't trust the conclusions at which our minds arrived. Therefore, if such a scenario were true, then we would suffer no loss from believing the "false" thing (in that case) that there were no such god.
This same sort of logic can go much further, and I am oversimplifying here. I think that we can likewise rule out, not as refuted but as impractical, many other types of potential deities as well, including apathetic ones. In fact, we may be able to establish some necessary features of an existing deity which much exist in any case that the question and answer are even important. I personally suspect that followed through, this might even narrow possible belief systems down to a single system, so I find it very useful.
Conclusion
So, no, you cannot refute the existence of such a thing. Also, no, you should not believe that such a thing exists.

Pure reason is sufficient to refute omnipotence; see this answer and comments.

@Corbin Neither the OP nor this answer assumes this hypothetical evil creator god is omnipotent; the closest was the OP referring to a counterargument that proceeded from that premise among other counterarguments that didn't. There's no necessity for a hypothetical creator god to be omnipotent; take Odin, for example, or Izanagi and Izanami, or Atum, or Mbombo.

Logical inconsistencies do not refute the possibility of omnipotence, of course. Such situations are not "things" but rather nonsense. God's inability to create logically impossible scenarios doesn't show Him to be less than omnipotent.

@Corbin I want to point out to any readers here the level of bad faith made in your comment. As Idran aptly observed, nothing in the OP nor this answer relate to omnipotence. (I never argue for omnipotence so defined) Nevertheless, you linked to an answer you gave on a question you asked, one which was closed because it was a poor duplicate of a highly ranked one where the answer is contrary. Furthermore, the answer you gave was the most downvoted and seemingly worst, yet you approved it as your own answer. I know that my comment here is off-topic, but I encourage others to check it out.

@HamSandwich: This is a common mistake which reduces God to the power level of humans. After all, via constructor theory, if we are limited to the constructible parts of physical reality then any construction can be performed by anybody and God trivializes. So no, you probably don't want to take that path.

@DKing: If the strongest argument you have against my position is that it is "bad faith" then you are tacitly admitting all of my deductions. At any rate, I'm merely explaining my downvote; your approach is decent but stumbles by giving God too much benefit of doubt. God is a self-defeating object, logically.

@Corbin Their argument against your position is that their answer doesn't mention omnipotence, nor does it refer specifically to the Abrahamic God. They aren't saying your position is in bad faith, but that your comment was made in bad faith because it's irrelevant to their answer. Their answer is about a hypothetical creator deity that may not necessarily be omnipotent, and so the logical impossibility of omnipotence doesn't provide a universal way of refuting all such hypothetical deities.

"Descartes says that the only thing we can know undeniably is the Cogito."  and even that I'm not sure about...

Per the wiki, constructor theory has to do with new physical laws being created, not the metaphysical laws of logic being violated.

"What if an evil god is deceiving humanity by allowing good things to exist, only to reveal its true nature and torture us after we die? This idea scares me, and I'm looking for arguments to refute it." (paraphrased)
In order, we would need to at least suppose there is a god, god cares, god has intentions, and good and evil exist.
Assuming all of these are true, and given you are happy to make so many assumptions, why not just make one more assumption about God, and assume a benevolent nature instead of going an extra step and making it more complicated?
We could forever build on your question with further qualifiers and ask if god is deceiving humanity while wearing a pink T-shirt, or while wearing a pink T-shirt and red shoes...
I believe what you are really asking is how many assumptions can you logically make about something, and that answer would have to be none.

I believe what they are actually asking is for somebody to gently lead them out of their funk ;-).

Believing in evil God leads to nihilism. If all the good work and sacrifices one makes results in suffering then there is no point in doing them. Anything that leads to Nihilism is wrong in my opinion because it contradicts the ends of belief itself. Therefore the idea of an evil God is wrong is because if making sacrifices for humanity and doing good works brings rewards, the goal of belief itself, then that is a sign that any God is good, rather than bad.
Billions believe in good God because it brings them fruits which they can cherish. What purpose would there be to believe in an evil and trickster God?
Instead of saying that there is an evil God it is more logical to believe in God and a Devil, with the former being able to reward you for good.
However faith in God and Devil are unscientific because no one has given direct evidence of God or Devil in modern times.

"Instead of saying that there is an Evil God it is more logical to believe in God and Devil.". Hm :-). A bold proposition! ;-)

Or perhaps another way of saying it, supposing there is only an evil God, choosing to believe instead in a God and Devil is in a way giving a big middle finger to that evil God, and with conscious knowledge of this you're basically insisting you're going to do good things anyway because it's the right thing to do.

Actually from a deistic point of view, when someone says that God is good, it is not meant a qualifier, but rather a definition. Like when we say a triangle is a geometric shape which has 3 sides. God, as the creator of everything, he is the one who sets up the rules, not only the physical laws but also for morality. He is the definition of good. Saying "an evil God" is like saying "a triangle with 4 sides". It's contradiction.
If you would want to morally judge God, you would need some kind of ethical codex by which you would judge him. But where would such a moral code come from? You cannot judge by your opinion, you need some universal, objective measure, which, in a world created by God, is God. If you measure God with his own measure, of course you'll get he is good.
Another perspective: If you think about God as an omnipotent being, then, if he was truly evil, he would optimize for the maximum suffering, without any happiness or peace for anyone. So the fact that there are some people who are able to be happy, even if for a limited amount of time, shows that either God is not omnipotent (so basically he's not God), or that he is not evil. If you would say that happy people are allowed to be happy just to make matters worse for everyone else, again, an omnipotent evil God would make sure everyone suffers equally, maximally.
EDIT: Also, if God is a perfect being in himself, meaning he is self-sufficient, he doesn't need anything, so he wouldn't benefit from torturing anyone.

@MisterMiyagi I agree that our suffering could be worse if someone near us is doing well. But two problems arise: 1) You can choose to ignore what other people are doing, or even more, if you're a selfless person, you can even be happy for other people's well being. And 2) as an omnipotent being, God could do anything to increase suffering, without others having a good time. As for your other comment, the judeo-christian view is that God didn't create us for his own happiness, but we were created to share in God's love. He doesn't need us, but we need him.

While I think you are right about the concept of calling a god evil, this is more about how do we know that there is not a god of a certain nature (what the OP might call "evil") which would including being a petty and immature trickster. Such an entity would not be bound by concepts such as self-sufficiency or even acting reasonably. Maybe he wouldn't even have to be omnipotent.

This answer seems to be assuming that the OP is saying "what if the universe was created by the Abrahamic God, but God is evil and trolling us". I'm pretty sure the OP is simply saying "what if the universe was created by an evil deity to troll us", with no claims that this hypothetical deity shares any qualities with the Abrahamic God other than having created the universe.

"But where would such a moral code come from?" This essentially paraphrases the question of "how can an atheist have morals?" which is a well-studied question and the foundation of the field of Ethics - the study of what is good and right, derived from first principles without reference to a higher power. This is Philosophy.SE, so from a philisophical viewpoint rather than a religious one, we can assume that a moral code can exist without a God (or else we must conclude that the study of ethics is futile and redundant), and that we can use ethical philosophy to determine what it is.

being a creator and being good because of that makes no logical sense. You can create things and be pretty cruel to them. Just because you can.

@Groovy That's not quite the deistic argument. The deistic argument (if I remember it right) isn't that God is good because he's the creator, but that God created the concept of morality alongside everything else, and so by definition anything he does is moral.

@DKing the OP mentions and refutes this argument: "If God is all-powerful, why would He create you, and this world with all its beauty, and your mind, and your soul, just to torture you?" That's why I assumed omnipotence, which, in my reading, comes with self-sufficience. But I agree that when we talk about a god, which is not the Abrahamic one, then we have to define its attributes, otherwise we're not talking about the same thing. I (mis?)interpreted the question as "what if the God who Christians and Jews adore is actually a sadistic maniac?".

@Idran It's true, I assumed something like this (see my response to DKing), but creating the universe out of nothing requires omnipotence. And besides omnipotence, I didn't assume the god in question to have any other attributes of the Abrahamic God (like omniscience, omnipresence, immutability etc.).

I'm not sure it does require omnipotence? Say, for example, a hypothetical deity that can create but can't destroy its creations, or a hypothetical deity that can only interact with its creations after their death. Or any other number of restrictions. After all, there are plenty of creator deities that are clearly not omnipotent in their own mythos.

Sure, we can assume these attributes about God, but now my question would be: is the OP's question a thought experiment, or are they interested whether this idea is true? If the former, than the discussion is like "if that would be the case, then A and B would happen." On the other hand, if the latter, than we have to be cautious about every assumption. What makes it rational to make one claim or another about (a) god?

the argument that God is good by definition can be the path to atheism if one assumes it as axiomatic and follows the evidence to the conclusion that all institutions that purport to have some contact with the divine are in fact completely man made.

As @bauerdavid mentioned

"If you would want to morally judge God, you would need some kind of
ethical codex by which you would judge him."

He then follows with God being ultimate source of this morality. Lets follow different path.
Let's follow this though experiment by Trent Horn in debate with CosmicSkeptic

All humans left Earth to colonize different planet. You are on the
last ship from earth. You are given antimatter device that will
instantly destroy Earth with animals. Would you destroy the earth to
prevent all future suffering of animals left on Earth?

If your answer is "No I would not destroy Earth", then that basically mean that you believe mere temporal existence of these beings is good (despite all the suffering they experience), non-existence being bad/evil.
You could argue that animals in the experiment above are not only tortured but perceive also some good and that is reason why their existence is good. But we would perceive good we had before even while being tormented for eternity (by definition of this trolling god).
So "Evil god" tormenting us for eternity can be considered good simply because god preserves our existence - it is not "Evil God" but "God the Preserver of Existence".
Now how does "Evil god" torment us for eternity? By thought experiment above, he could torment us simply by ending our existence (and as a troll, he would tell us this just before ending our existence). Then it comes to whether temporal existence was worth eternal non-existence.
As an amateur in philosophy and someone believing in existence = good, I find this strong argument against such god, but I am sure many arguments could be made (against this position) by Philosophical pessimism

Interesting answer but I have to say what do we interpret as ending our life? Because if we are already near god/in hell, we have already died. And we have been transferred here. If god again killed us, would we transfer somewhere else? Or would we just be resurrected for eternal punishment. The thing I am trying to convey is that through conservation of mass destruction would be impossible. You can say god transcends all logic and humanity but the thought of real destruction is horrifying as in what comes after is uncertain...

...All in all, for example, if god keeps killing us over and over again, would that be good or bad? Technically our existence is being repeatedly wiped but we are also being put into existence again. So that would be both non-existence and existence, which is still not preferable to simple existence. Another thing to note is that evil is subjective. Anyways what would be your reaction to the argument I have presented as a believer of existence = good?

@The_AH well, there is end of life (on Earth) and end of existence (aka Soul) and that can also be same thing (if there is no Soul). If my Soul would preserve between each time I die that is reincarnation. Also I am not sure how would previous lives have any impact in case of this evil troll god - during life we would remember only good and evil in our current earthly life (and in between remember everything?). If my Soul would not preserve (or there is no Soul) after death, than I would not consider new me as me, but someone else - I would live earthly life once and then non-exist for ever.

I suppose we're getting too off-topic but we get to the problem of that wouldn't be you, what would happen to the old you, that would still be destroyed, an entirely new reincarnation would be born but old you would still be killed or destroyed, and we get back to conservation of mass. The only logical way that an evil god can repeatedly kill is if we define killing as the transformation of your atoms all to nothing, but what is destruction if not the transformation of atoms to nothing? So we could say destruction is possible since we are just transforming. But the soul is not measured..

..in scientific or physical terms but is rather a broad concept not pertaining at all to any forms of logic. And so a soul cannot realistically be destroyed as we don't even know it's properties. This would mean however there would be still a soul to experience the destruction, which itself would be absolutely horrifying and I am not sure how this can be phrased as anyway except evil.

@The_AH thinking about it, Soul is irrelevant for this question, because god could do the same to physical body - killing it instead of soul annihilation, or prolong bodily functions for eternity, instead of eternal existence of soul.

honestly that just seems to dodge my question, but as I said the definition of killing here is subjective.

@The_AH your comments have a lot of questions and I can't answer them all, simply because there is a lot to say. As I understand it your argument would be that repeated killing (existence and non-existence) is evil or at least worse than permanent existence, but if there is a non-existence then I argue another existence is not the same person/soul, so this would be impossible. I agree that eternal death is evil, but then it comes to what I said in answer - does "temporal existence was worth eternal non-existence". So this evil god could still be interpreted as good in some sense.

I have some more to say, we can move this to chat if you are interested.

In its purest form, evil is destructive, so if a god was evil, he would destroy everything he possibly could. If he were absolutely powerful, then there would be nothing left.
If a god is just messing with us, sometimes being evil and sometimes being kind for no reason, I would argue that this god is not totally evil. He is only partially evil, since by our definition above, total evil necessitates total destruction.
So I would argue that a god who is trolling humanity is not totally evil, but also contains some good.
I think you would argue that a god who does bad 90% of the time and happens to do good 10% of the time is by definition evil. I would argue that he is 90% evil.
So in this case, we could pose the question: Where does the good in this mostly-evil god come from? Some higher power? And where does the evil come from? Some other higher power? Any god that is caught between good and evil is mostly likely being manipulated by other, higher, purer forms of good and evil. So he is not the highest power; there are higher all-good and all-evil beings above him.

Why do you need a pure evil / good being for beings to exist that are a mix of those qualities? For any quality, there is a being that is closest to pure in that quality. However, that does not entail the existence of a being that reaches 100%.
I also cannot agree, that pure evil must be just destructive. Taking delight in suffering and despair is plenty evil for me. It is hard to argue that creating a world to torment (and maybe toss it later) would be a good act. Of course, this hinges on definitions of good and evil.

Does the poultry or steer farmer do his job from malice to the 'beings' he 'creates' ie breeds? We do not ask whether the calamity of a tsunami or earthquake is malicious even if it is traumatic/deadly for a million humans.
While tsunamis and such are large-scale catastrophes by the human scale, the creation of the world — assuming such an event or process has any meaning — must clearly be a cosmic event or process of vastly more...
Gigantic proportions
To even begin to grok these effectively infinite proportions,
consider the following sequence of catastrophes made with assistance from chatGPT.


Personal Incident:
Example: Car accident.
Impact: Affects one or a few individuals, causing injury or death.

Localized Emergency:
Example: House fire.
Impact: Affects a single household or small group, leading to loss of property, injury, or death.

Community Disaster:
Example: Industrial accident (e.g., factory explosion).
Impact: Affects dozens to hundreds of people, causing injuries, fatalities, and environmental damage.

Citywide Crisis:
Example: Terrorist attack (e.g., bombing in a major city).
Impact: Affects thousands, causing widespread fear, significant casualties, and economic disruption.

Regional Catastrophe:
Example: Major earthquake or tsunami.
Impact: Affects tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands, leading to large-scale destruction, significant loss of life, and displacement.

National Disaster:
Example: Category 5 hurricane.
Impact: Affects millions, causing extensive damage, long-term economic impact, and numerous casualties.

Continental Crisis:
Example: Severe drought or pandemic outbreak.
Impact: Affects tens of millions, leading to widespread health issues, economic downturns, and significant mortality.

Global Threat:
Example: Large-scale war or nuclear conflict.
Impact: Affects billions, causing massive casualties, widespread destruction, and global instability.

Intra-Planetary Catastrophe:
Example: Ocean levels rising dramatically due to climate change.
Impact: Affects entire populations worldwide, leading to mass displacement, economic collapse, and severe loss of life.

Extinction-Level Event:
Example: Comet or asteroid impact.
Impact: Potentially wipes out most or all life on Earth, leading to the end of human civilization and mass extinction of species.

Inter-Planetary Catastrophe:
Example: Cataclysmic events leading to the formation of a new planet eg. planet theia colliding with the earth and producing the moon.
Impact: Disrupts the structure and dynamics of an existing solar system, causing widespread destruction of pre-existing celestial bodies and potentially creating hazardous environments. These events can entirely obliterate existing forms of life while also laying the groundwork for new ones to emerge.

Stellar Explosion —Supernovae, GRB):
Example: A star going supernova.
Impact: Destroys nearby stars, and their solar systems and creating black holes or neutron stars.

Galactic Collision:
Example: Collision and merging of galaxies.
Impact: Massive restructuring of stars and planetary systems, potentially causing widespread destruction and the formation of new star systems.

Cosmic Events:
Example: Big Bang or similar universe-creating events.
Impact: Fundamental events that create entire universes, leading to the formation of all matter, energy, stars, galaxies, and potentially life.



I particularly recommend the comments below the link in 10. as answer to this question.
Religion-Philosophy : Contradictory or Complementary?
It's a strange phenomenon — people tend to project onto God the very first and last levels but not the ones in between which they ascribe "secularly" — science, politics, (human) nature etc. Such exceptionalism is neither...
Good science nor Good religion
A saner approach would be to say "all" or "none."
Generally speaking "all" is called "religion" — God is the all-doer, all-controller.
"None" is called "philosophy" — these are all processes. Pushing malice, "trolling", grace, good, evil, sin, redemption etc., — all may be termed subspecies of the process called "ignorance" (maya) + "suffering" (dukha).
Analogy
Can a cell in your brain, even one in the intellectual areas of the cortex, contemplate the cortex, Can it contemplate the brain? You and your identity?  Sure it participates but it cannot really know in what it participates.
Changing the analogy slightly consider a muscle cell. Now consider you go to the gym, pump some iron, get red in the face and break some muscle fibres towards increasing your muscle mass. At your level its huffing panting and sweating. At the level of the muscle tissue its more calamitous. At the levels of the muscle cell its life and death. Does that make you cruel? "Trolling"?
Christianity is a bit strange in axiomatically defining God to be "omnibenevolent".
But Good-Evil is the fundamental defining axis of Christianity.
If you find it depressing/ claustrophobic/frightening there are other axes you might find more agreeable.
Eastern religions are more balanced in this respect,  eg. in the Bhagavad Gita, Krishna broadly recommends bhakti (religion) and jnana (philosophy) to Arjuna and never allows Arjuna to fall entirely to one or other side.
You may find looking Eastwards — there's a wide palette — more relaxing than getting stuck between Christianity and atheism.

Atheism is illogical and self-defeating. People reject God for emotional reasons, which is worthless.

@HamSandwich While I've +1ed your comment for the evaluation of atheism, "Emotional reasons are worthless " doesn't square with the actuality of religion. In short ppl are emotional about their (conventional) religions, ppls are emotional about their faux religions like atheism, liberalism, democracy etc.

Yes, people can be emotional about religion as well.

@HamSandwich your statement makes no sense to me.  some people just follow where the evidence leads...

I don't think anyone is truly unbiased when it comes to such matters.
